# Google visualization DataTable: calculate totals

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm searching a way to add a row of totals to a simple DataTable. This is my code:

```
// Create and populate the data table.
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dt.addColumn('string', 'Name');
dt.addColumn('number', 'Height');

dt.addRows([
    ['Tong Ning mu', 174],
    ['Huang Ang fa', 523],
    ['Teng nu', 86]
]);

var myTotal;
/* calculate total sum of column Height */
dt.addRow(['TOTAL', myTotal]);

// Create and draw the visualization.
visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
visualization.draw(dt, null);
```

How to calculate `myTotal` from `dt` DataTable?

Is it possible to make the last row(Totals) bold?

Is there any more elegant way to add totals to a table?

Answer (score 1):

create the following function:

```
function getSum(data, column) {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++)
        total = total + data.getValue(i, column);
    return total;
}
```

call it with your created google datatable, and column array index. In your case:

```
var total = getSum(dt,1);
```

Then, you can add that total into a new raw or what ever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Danny's reply is the same solution as I would say for suming the column, I won't write it.

To set a *cell* property you `dataTable.setProperty(columnIndex,rowIndex,'style','font-weight:bold;');`

so in your case you'd write 
`dt.setProperty(0, 3, 'style','font-weight:bold;');
dt.setProperty(1, 3, 'style','font-weight:bold;');`

Say you provide a bit bigger dataTable, it might be inconvenient to type this for all cells, you could use a for loop like (to make the whole last row bold):

```
var lastRow = dt.getNumberOfRows()-1
for (i=0, n=dt.getNumberOfColumns(); i < n; i++) {
   dt.setProperty(i, lastRow, 'style', 'font-weight:bold;');
}
```

Sadly you're unable to set properties to a whole row/column (see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#customproperties) about custom properties regarding this).